# Create transform to map from one rectangle to another?

Tags: java, awt, transformation, rectangles, affinetransform

What is the simplest way to create `AffineTransform` which maps coordinates from one rectangle to another (float/double rectangles are given)?

**UPDATE 1**

Rectangles can be absolutely different. For example [(0,0)-(1,1)] and [(150,-14)-(-1000,-14.1)]. And transformation should transform uniformly. For example, rectangle corners should be transformed one to one. For example coordinates (0,0) should turn to (150,-14).

**UPDATE 2**

I need `AffineTransform` object, not just calculation. Because I want to apply it to `Graphics` object. Also I would like to have in the form of some concatenation of simple transforms.

**UPDATE 3**

All the following 3 tests are failed:

```
public class RectangleTransformTest {

    private static final double delta = 0.001;

    Rectangle2D r1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(-1, 0, 2, 0.01);
    Rectangle2D r2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 20, 400, 300);

    AffineTransform t;

    Point2D src;
    Point2D dst1, dst2;

    @Test
    public void test1() {

        t = new AffineTransform();
        t.translate(+r2.getMinX()-r1.getMinX(), +r2.getMinY()-r1.getMinY());
        t.scale(r2.getWidth()/r1.getWidth(), r2.getHeight()/r1.getHeight());

    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {

        t = new AffineTransform();

        t.scale(r2.getWidth()/r1.getWidth(), r2.getHeight()/r1.getHeight());
        t.translate(+r2.getMinX()-r1.getMinX(), +r2.getMinY()-r1.getMinY());

    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {

        t = new AffineTransform();

        t.scale((r2.getMaxX()-r2.getMinX())/(r1.getMaxX()-r1.getMinX()), (r2.getMaxY()-r2.getMinY())/(r1.getMaxY()-r1.getMinY()));
        t.translate(+r2.getMinX()-r1.getMinX(), +r2.getMinY()-r1.getMinY());

    }

    @After
    public void comparePoints() {

        src = new Point2D.Double(r1.getMinX(), r1.getMinY());
        dst1 =  new Point2D.Double();
        t.transform(src, dst1);
        dst2 = new Point2D.Double(r2.getMinX(), r2.getMinY());

        assertEquals(dst2.getX(), dst1.getX(), delta);
        assertEquals(dst2.getY(), dst1.getY(), delta);

        src = new Point2D.Double(r1.getMinX(), r1.getMaxY());
        dst1 =  new Point2D.Double();
        t.transform(src, dst1);
        dst2 = new Point2D.Double(r2.getMinX(), r2.getMaxY());

        assertEquals(dst2.getX(), dst1.getX(), delta);
        assertEquals(dst2.getY(), dst1.getY(), delta);

        src = new Point2D.Double(r1.getMaxX(), r1.getMinY());
        dst1 =  new Point2D.Double();
        t.transform(src, dst1);
        dst2 = new Point2D.Double(r2.getMaxX(), r2.getMinY());

        assertEquals(dst2.getX(), dst1.getX(), delta);
        assertEquals(dst2.getY(), dst1.getY(), delta);

        src = new Point2D.Double(r1.getMaxX(), r1.getMaxY());
        dst1 =  new Point2D.Double();
        t.transform(src, dst1);
        dst2 = new Point2D.Double(r2.getMaxX(), r2.getMaxY());

        assertEquals(dst2.getX(), dst1.getX(), delta);
        assertEquals(dst2.getY(), dst1.getY(), delta);

    }

}
```

Comment: [`AffineTransform#getTranslateInstance(double, double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getTranslateInstance%28double,%20double%29) ... You question is a little vague on details

Comment: Do you mean you have two *given* rectangles and want do derive the transformation between them? - Which transformation(s) will be needed, translation, rotation, scaling?

Comment: @Hanno I will need all transformations required by rectangles. For example if rectangles are equal, then it should be `Identity` transformation.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, this is just translation. I need also the scale if rectangles are of different size.

Comment: "all transformations required by rectangles" - this includes rotation since a rotated rectangle is still a rectangle, whereas, for example, a sheared rectangle is not a rectangle after the transformation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To transform from [(a,b)-(c,d)] to [(e,f)-(g,h)] you can perform the following computation:

```
x' = e + (x - a) * (g - e) / (c - a);
y' = f + (y - b) * (h - f) / (d - b);
```

Here is the corresponding `AffineTransform` code, where `r1` is being transformed to `r2`:

```
t = new AffineTransform();
t.translate(r2.getMinX(), r2.getMinY());
t.scale(r2.getWidth()/r1.getWidth(), r2.getHeight()/r1.getHeight());    
t.translate(-r1.getMinX(), -r1.getMinY());
```

Comment: I need `AffineTransform` object.

Comment: Then you need to concatenate a `getScaleInstance((g - e) / (c - a), (h - f) / (d - b))` and a `getTranslateInstance( e-a, f-b )`.

Comment: @Sam ah great I didn't think about such variant. Note that your exact version does not work, you should inverse location of translates.

Comment: @Dims Thanks, I'll fix it. It's also possible to do it with only one translate but I really don't think it's worth the complexity.

Comment: What is the x and y in the input, and the x' and Y'  in the computation at the start @samhocevar ?

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy *(x,y)* are the coordinates of any point inside the initial rectangle, and *(x',y')* are the coordinates of the transformed point in the destination rectangle.

Comment: Has anyone had rounding errors using the computation method? I am using this and I am finding that sometimes I need to Round Up to get the correct Point, and sometimes I need to round down. Should a scaling factor be used?