# How to find the center/axe of rotation?

Tags: java, c++, 3d, transformation

I have 2 3d models and have arrays of all their points and their correspondence. I know that the second model is the first one but after rigid transformation. I also know the type of that transformation - translation or rotation. I need to calculate the axis/center of transformation and it's value - angle or distance. Case with translation is very simple. But I can't find solution for rotation. More over I need to find the axis location relative to one of the model. So only the coordinates of vector defining the axis aren't enough. How can this problem be solved? 
P.S.: I use Java and C++ but even theoretical explanation will help me a lot.

Comment: This is closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270892/generate-affinetransform-from-3-points/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to registrate two models. Maybe you should have a look at [ICP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) and [Registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_set_registration).

You didn't state it, but I assume the correspondences aren't exact, i.e. noisy.

Comment: Correspondence is absolute, because model 1 and model 2 are 3d scans of the same object.

Comment: Yes, and because the objects are scanned, the correspondences won't be exact.